# Check pointwise and uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Check for the below the pointwise and uniform convergence.

- $\displaystyle{f_n(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}}, \ x\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\displaystyle{g_n(x)=n^2xe^{-nx}}, \ x\in \mathbb{R}^+$
- $\displaystyle{h_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}}, \ x\in \mathbb{R}$

For the pointwise convergence we have to calculate the limit as $n\rightarrow +\infty$ and if we get a function $f\neq \infty$ then it converges, right?

we have the following:

- For $x\neq 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{n\left (xn^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right )}{n\left (\frac{1}{n}+x^2\right )}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{xn^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{n}+x^2}=\frac{0}{0+x^2}=0$$ For $x= 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{0}{1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}0=0$$ Therefore $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise, right?
- For $x\neq 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}g_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n^2xe^{-nx}\overset{\text{De L'Hopital}}{=}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2n}{x^2e^{nx}}\overset{\text{De L'Hopital}}{=}\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{2}{x^3e^{nx}}=0$$ For $x= 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}g_n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}0=0$$ Therefore $g_n(x)$ converges pointwise, right?
- For $x\neq 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}h_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}$$ We have that \begin{align*}-1\leq \sin nx\leq 1&\Rightarrow -\frac{1}{1+nx^2}\leq \frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}\leq \frac{1}{1+nx^2}\\ & \Rightarrow -\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{1+nx^2}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{1+nx^2} \\ & \Rightarrow -0\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}\leq 0\end{align*} Therefore $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2}=0$ For $x= 0$ we have that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}h_n(0)=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{0}{1}=0$$ So $h_n(x)$ converges pointwise, right?

How can we check the uniform convergence?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Do we maybe do the following for the uniform convergence?

\begin{align*}&f_n(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{n}}{1+nx^2}\\ &\rightarrow f_n'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{n}(1+nx^2)-x\sqrt{n}2nx}{(1+nx^2)^2}=\frac{\sqrt{n}-n\sqrt{n}x^2}{(1+nx^2)^2} =\frac{\sqrt{n}\left (1-nx^2\right )}{(1+nx^2)^2} \\ & \rightarrow f'_n(x)=0 \Rightarrow \sqrt{n}\left (1-nx^2\right )=0 \Rightarrow 1-nx^2=0 \Rightarrow x^2=\frac{1}{n}\Rightarrow x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \\ & f_n\left (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right )=\frac{-1}{2} \\ & f_n\left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right )=\frac{1}{2}\end{align*}
So the maximum is $\frac{1}{2}$. For $n\rightarrow +\infty$ the limit is $\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$, so this sequence does not converge uniformly. Is this correct?

\begin{align*}&g_n(x)=n^2xe^{-nx}\\ &\rightarrow g_n'(x)=n^2e^{-nx}-n^3xe^{-nx}=\left (n^2-n^3x\right )e^{-nx} \\ &\rightarrow g_n'(x)=0 \Rightarrow \left (n^2-n^3x\right )e^{-nx}=0 \Rightarrow n^2-n^3x=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \\ &g_n\left (\frac{1}{n}\right )=\frac{n}{e}\end{align*} So the maximum is $\frac{n}{e}$. For $n\rightarrow +\infty$ the limit is $+\infty\neq 0$, so this sequence does not converge uniformly. Is this correct?

\begin{align*}|h_n(x)|=\left |\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx^2} \right |\leq \frac{ nx}{1+nx^2}\end{align*} How do we continue?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy the last answer dates back to 2016. Either a different person, or some very serious circumstances

Comment: The question is rather "how to solve" instead of "solve it for me and give me the whole solution" and a few insights from the author are given. Of course he could have shown more effort, but I feel this is not that wrong.

Comment: If OP posted 10 or 15 sequences would that be fine too? I object to the posting of three sequences. To know the procedure for proving unifom convergence one sequuence would have been enough.  @nicomezi

Comment: The adequate "procedure" heavily depends on the sequence of function. The current answer suggests using the derivative for example. While it could be an easy way with some sequences, here there are simpler ways. I agree that the question feels "empty", but not enough to deserve that much downvotes in my opinion. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I added what I have done for the pointwise convergence. Is everything correct? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I added what I have done for the pointwise convergence. Is everything correct? @Alex

Comment: I added what I have done for the pointwise convergence. Is everything correct? @nicomezi

Comment: You have to consider $x=0$ separately in all cases.

Comment: I added that, is this part now correct and complete? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I have also an other question. If we would get an other limit for $x=0$ and an other for $x\neq 0$, would it mean again that it converges pointwise? @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1):

Most easy is to use necessary and sufficient  condition
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)| =0$$
and for $\sup$ is possible to use derivative, for example.

Let's take for 1st one $f^{'}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{n}(1-nx^2)}{(1+nx^2)^2}$. These gives extremums for $f$ in $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ so maximum will be $\frac{1}{2}$. Of course derivative is only one, but powerful, tool for finding $\sup$.

Comment: The derivative is not useful with these examples. Also, we rather say : "necessary and sufficient condition".

Comment: @nicomezi. Thanks for "necessary and sufficient condition" - I change wording. But your remark about derivative is very doubtful. I wrote example mainly for you.

Comment: I just wanted to highligh that using derivative is heavy machinery for such examples, this is what I meant by "not useful". The first example can be solved by noting $|x \sqrt n| \le \sqrt n$ on $[-1,1]$ and $|x \sqrt n| < \sqrt{1+nx^2}$ otherwise since the limit is $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: I added what I have done for the pointwise convergence. Is everything correct? @zkutch

Comment: @Mary Star. Yes, pointwise convergence is done properly, only for third, imho, is more easy and short to write $|\sin nx| \leqslant 1$, but what you done is same.

Comment: Ok, great!! Could you take also a look at the Edit part of my original post? @zkutch

Comment: @Mary Star. Boundedness is not enough. After you find upper limit, but better to find $\sup$, then you need check if limit of it is $0$ - exact formulation and 1-st example look up in my answer. Write, if something unclear.

Comment: For the first one : the maximum is $\frac{1}{2}$. For $n\rightarrow +\infty$ the limit is $\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$, so this sequence does not converge uniformly. For the second sequence : the maximum is $\frac{n}{e}$.For $n\rightarrow +\infty$ the limit is $+\infty\neq 0$, so this sequence does not converge uniformly. Is everything correct so far? Could you give me a hint for the third sequence? @zkutch

Comment: Or do we have to do something else? @zkutch

Comment: I added this approach to my original post. Could you take a look? Or do you mean it in an other way? @zkutch

Comment: @Mary Star. Sorry, but I am not at computer all the time, especially on weekends. I'm happy to help, but if you need it at any particular time, you should at least warn me in advance. Glad that you have already been helped. I think it would be correct to open a separate question for each example separately.

Answer (score 1):

What you did for the first two sequences is correct. Concerning the third one, use the fact that$$|h_n(x)|\leqslant\frac1{1+nx^2}$$and that $h_n(0)=0$ to deduce that that sequence converges pointwise to the null function. After that, use the fact that$$h_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac{\sin 1}{1+\frac1n}\text{ and that }\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1}{1+\frac1n}=\sin1\neq0.$$

Comment: As for the ffirst two sequences instead of "maximum" I have to say "supremum" or not?

Comment: In both cases, it is really a maximum. So, there is no reason for you not to use $\max$.

Comment: Ok! Could you explain to me the second part of your answer about $h_n$ ? Does this mean that the supremum doesn't go $0$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$ ?

Comment: Why do we check the sequence at $x=\frac{1}{n}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|h_n(x)-0|=0$. And I tried $\frac1n$ because it looked like it could work. And it did!